# need help in ( appSetting values in .aspx file ) RSS

Tags: database-connection, appsettings

i configured my web.config  to sql server database as this

```
<appSettings>
<add key="OnlineDiscussionSqlCon" value="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OnlineDiscussionForum;Integrated Security=True" />
```

thats working fine,

but i cannot access my database in .aspx files

my .aspx file is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/User/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WelcomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="User_WelcomePage" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<table style="width: 560px; position: static">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" >
            Wel come To User</td>
        <td >
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."
                Style="position: static;" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BookName" HeaderText="BookName" SortExpression="BookName" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ appSettings:OnlineDiscussionSqlCon %>"
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [TblNewbookAlert] WHERE [ID] = @ID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [TblNewbookAlert] ([BookName]) VALUES (@BookName)"

                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [BookName] FROM [TblNewbookAlert]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [TblNewbookAlert] SET [BookName] = @BookName WHERE [ID] = @ID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="BookName" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="BookName" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i tried many ways but i did not got fixed ,

please can any one help me here.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use "Data Source=**YourServerName\YourSqlServerInstanceName**" instead of "Data Source=." in the web.config file.